# Get currentDevice Context in DX9.0c

Tags: directx-9

I have a framework (so I don't inject anything to a running process) that uses DX9.0c and WinApi to create a Window and initialize DirectX. However, I do not have either device context nor HWND. Is there any way to obtain device context in this situation? Or should I try to create dummy HWND and create a new device context?

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer accepted whenever it helped (most) in solving the problem. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Answer (score 0):

Use NULL as a parameter for `CreateCompatibleDC` to get an device context which is compatible to your screen.

`HDC hdcDC = ::CreateCompatibleDC( NULL );`

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183489(v=vs.85).aspx for more details.